# VS2017 not showing Report Viewer in prerequisites

Tags: visual-studio-2017, report-viewer2016

I am trying to deploy a wpf application with an embedded rdlc report using clickonce.  The previous version of report viewer (in VS2015) was built-in so it was easy and convenient to use and I had no issues deploying this project.

Now since easy and convenient is not the goal anymore, in vs2017 after a failed deploy with an error message that gave me absolutely no help, I have come to realize that apparently you have to install 2 additional VS extensions and a report viewer runtime on every machine where an app uses and rdlc reports (feels like crystal reports all over again) and you have to exclude the automatically included Chinese localization files in your clickonce deployment (which cause a manifest parse error).  Anyway, the instructions on MS [website](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251723.aspx) say that click once should have a "Microsoft Visual Studio Report Viewer" prerequisite option to select as requirement of installing your app.  However, after installing the runtime on my development machine, restarting visual studio, this option is not available.  Does anyone know how to get this to work?

Comment: Can't get the pre-requisite to appear no matter what I do.  For now I have reverted to using vs2015 until this stuff is more sanely implemented.

Answer (score 0):

I used Project|Manage NuGet Packages to add this package to my project.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ReportViewer.Runtime.Common/12.0.2402.15

If you search with Manage NuGet Packages, there's quite a few ReportViewer related items.  I'm not sure which ones are appropriate to your WPF app.

Anyway, the deployment project picked up the various ReportViewer assembly dependencies and everything seems to be working without the EXE redist from MS.